# Processing triggers result in "skipping file because of errors", expected: '='

Tags: apt

After installing any program using apt-get, the following lines of code appear in the terminal:

[image]

This problem seems to be related to the file `wxmaxima.menu`, so I opened it up and took a look.

```
?package(wxmaxima):\ needs="X11"\
section="Applications/Science/Mathematics"\ title="wxMaxima"\
longtitle="GUI for the computer algebra system Maxima"\
icon16x16="/usr/share/pixmaps/wxmaxima-16.xpm"\
icon32x32="/usr/share/pixmaps/wxmaxima-32.xpm"\
command="/usr/bin/wxmaxima"
```

I then compared it to another "menu" file, this one being from Transmission:

```
?package(transmission-gtk):needs="X11" 
section="Applications/Network/File Transfer" \
title="Transmission BitTorrent Client (GTK)" command="/usr/bin/transmission-gtk" \
icon="/usr/share/pixmaps/transmission.xpm"
```

The error message stated that it expected a "=" sign, but it's clearly there. As well, I don't see any difference between the wxmaxima and transmission menu files (expect that the wxmaxima one causes an error).

Can someone shine some light on this?

UPDATE: Here's the output from *apt-cache policy wxmaxima; lsb_release -a*

```
wxmaxima:
Installed: 15.08.2-1~ppa3~vivid
Candidate: 15.08.2-1~ppa3~vivid
Version table:
*** 15.08.2-1~ppa3~vivid 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy wxmaxima; lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 0):

In modern Desktop Environments `menu` files are not necessary. Therefore you can ignore the error message. A working `desktop` file is important.

---

But you could try to fix your `menu` file via

```
sudo nano /usr/share/menu/wxmaxima
```

and add the following

```
?package(wxmaxima):\
    needs="X11"\
    section="Applications/Science/Mathematics"\
    title="wxMaxima"\
    longtitle="GUI for the computer algebra system Maxima"\
    icon16x16="/usr/share/pixmaps/wxmaxima-16.xpm"\
    icon32x32="/usr/share/pixmaps/wxmaxima-32.xpm"\
    command="/usr/bin/wxmaxima"
```

After that start

```
sudo update-menus
```